# DataTable giving error while loading Large number of column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```js
$(function() {
 var aoColumns=[{"sTitle":"REGION."},{"sTitle"
  :"TOTAL TSI."},{"sTitle":"branchId"},{"sTitle":1},{"sTitle":"1 % AGE"},{"sTitle":2},{"sTitle":"2 % AGE"
  },{"sTitle":3},{"sTitle":"3 % AGE"},{"sTitle":4},{"sTitle":"4 % AGE"},{"sTitle":5},{"sTitle":"5 % AGE"
  },{"sTitle":6},{"sTitle":"6 % AGE"},{"sTitle":7},{"sTitle":"7 % AGE"},{"sTitle":8},{"sTitle":"8 % AGE"
  },{"sTitle":9},{"sTitle":"9 % AGE"},{"sTitle":10},{"sTitle":"10 % AGE"},{"sTitle":11},{"sTitle":"11 % AGE"},{"sTitle":12},{"sTitle":"12 % AGE"},{"sTitle":13},{"sTitle":"13 % AGE"},{"sTitle":14},{"sTitle"
  :"14 % AGE"},{"sTitle":15},{"sTitle":"15 % AGE"},{"sTitle":16},{"sTitle":"16 % AGE"},{"sTitle":17},{"sTitle"
  :"17 % AGE"},{"sTitle":18},{"sTitle":"18 % AGE"},{"sTitle":19},{"sTitle":"19 % AGE"},{"sTitle":20},{"sTitle"
  :"20 % AGE"},{"sTitle":21},{"sTitle":"21 % AGE"},{"sTitle":22},{"sTitle":"22 % AGE"},{"sTitle":23},{"sTitle"
  :"23 % AGE"},{"sTitle":24},{"sTitle":"24 % AGE"},{"sTitle":25},{"sTitle":"25 % AGE"},{"sTitle":26},{"sTitle"
  :"26 % AGE"},{"sTitle":27},{"sTitle":"27 % AGE"}];
 var aaData=[["Visakhapatnam","7","6676",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
              ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
 $('#performanceTable').dataTable({
  "bJQueryUI" : true,
  "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
  "sScrollY" : 320,
  "bDestroy": true,
  "scrollX": true,
  "aaData" : aaData,
  "aoColumns" : aoColumns,

 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="performanceTable"    style="cellspacing:0;width:100%;" class="display"></table>
```

Getting error something like:

> TypeError: c.sTitle.replace is not a function

Help Required..........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with datatables.js, but the .replace function relies on the variable being a string but I can see in the data there are integers assigned to Title. Rings alarm bells...though datatables might cope with it. Does it still happen if you surround your title numbers in "".

Comment: Have upvoted Epirocks . Got this in the console = "jquery.dataTables.min.js:67 Uncaught TypeError: c.sTitle.replace is not a function" . was sending dataTable , a dataframe from Python with Column Headers as Integers .

Answer (score 1):

All sTitle values must be strings so instead of "sTitle" : 1 use "sTitle" : "1" and so on

```
j$(function() {
var aoColumns=[{"sTitle":"REGION."},{"sTitle"
    :"TOTAL TSI."},{"sTitle":"branchId"},{"sTitle":"1"},{"sTitle":"1 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"2"},{"sTitle":"2 % AGE"
    },{"sTitle":"3"},{"sTitle":"3 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"4"},{"sTitle":"4 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"5"},{"sTitle":"5 % AGE"
    },{"sTitle":"6"},{"sTitle":"6 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"7"},{"sTitle":"7 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"8"},{"sTitle":"8 % AGE"
    },{"sTitle":"9"},{"sTitle":"9 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"10"},{"sTitle":"10 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"11"},{"sTitle":"11 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"12"},{"sTitle":"12 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"13"},{"sTitle":"13 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"14"},{"sTitle"
    :"14 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"15"},{"sTitle":"15 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"16"},{"sTitle":"16 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"17"},{"sTitle"
    :"17 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"18"},{"sTitle":"18 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"19"},{"sTitle":"19 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"20"},{"sTitle"
    :"20 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"21"},{"sTitle":"21 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"22"},{"sTitle":"22 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"23"},{"sTitle"
    :"23 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"24"},{"sTitle":"24 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"25"},{"sTitle":"25 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"26"},{"sTitle"
    :"26 % AGE"},{"sTitle":"27"},{"sTitle":"27 % AGE"}];

var aaData=[["Visakhapatnam","7","6676",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
             ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];

j$('#performanceTable').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI" : true,
    "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
    "sScrollY" : 320,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "scrollX": true,
    "aaData" : aaData,
    "aoColumns" : aoColumns,

});
```

});

Hope it helps, 
Dan